# Why do we use pointers instead of simply creating an array of specific size?

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, dynamic-memory-allocation

I'm new to C++ and sorry if this has been asked before but I couldn't find it.
Why do we use pointers instead of simply creating an array of specific size?

```
  int** ary = new int*[rowCount];
   for(int i = 0; i < rowCount; ++i)
    ary[i] = new int[colCount];
```

and

```
int ary[rowCount][colCount];
```

what's the difference between the two?
I know that first one works on heap memory and second one on stack but why most people work with 1st method?

Comment: the efficiency/power of the language allows you to work with memory places instead of huge data-objects......

Comment: since you are new to c++ you will for sure find more info about the pros (and pitfalls) of referring things by the memory where they are allocated...

Comment: Imagine this.  You are going to put a bunch of blocks on a table..  The table has a BUNCH of junk on it.  Would you rather:  1) have all the blocks taped together, and then have to move around everything on the table such that it fits.... or 2) put the blocks whereever they fit on the table and then just remember the location of where the blocks are.  In both cases, you know nothing about any of the blocks, but you know where they all are.  One of the issues when dealing with stuff is that when you are done dealing with blocks, in both cases you want to remember to remove all of the blocks.

Comment: The main difference between your two code snippets is stack vs heap allocation. The first will allocate from the heap, while the second will be on the stack. The first requires you to manually release the memory with an explicit `delete` statement, while the second will be automatically released when leaving the current scope. Each is appropriate for different scenarios and so it depends on what you are trying to do.

Comment: These are concepts that a novice C++ programmer will learn when going through their initial courses of study, through books presentations etc.  It is an inherited concept from C.

Comment: Prefer to use `std::vector` instead of arrays.  The `std::vector` class handles dynamic memory management for you.  Also, the `std::vector` maintains attributes like size.

Answer (score 1):

One difference is that the second one will only compile if both rowCount and colCount are [constant expressions](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constant_expression). See also [Array declaration](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/array).

The first one, on the other hand, compiles even if these variables change during runtime.

By the way, all this is similar to C. If you are using C++, you are better using `std::vector` for the first option and `std::array` for the second.